# Can't install VirtualBox on Raspberry Pi

Tags: virtualbox, raspberrypi, 22.04

I have search a lot in different forums to solve this, not found any working for me though.

I have a Raspberry Pi 4. I have made a new image with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS (RPi 4/400) with Raspberry Pi Imager v1.7.2

After doing `sudo apt update` I'd like to install VirtualBox. I tried `sudo apt install virtualbox` but I get

> Package 'virtualbox' is not available, but is referred to by another package

Any suggestion would be great! Maybe I am downloading wrong image?

Comment: `virtalbox` is available for *amd64* architecture, ie. `virtualbox | 6.1.32-dfsg-1build1                 | jammy/multiverse           | source, amd64`  but the raspberry pi is *armhf* or *arm64* which is the wrong architecture; thus cannot install/run `virtualbox`

Comment: Bottom line, VirtualBox won't run on a Raspberry Pi or on your phone.

Comment: Thanks for the information !!

Answer (score 9):

`virtalbox` is available for [*amd64* architecture](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virtualbox&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all), ie.

`virtualbox | 6.1.32-dfsg-1build1                 | jammy/multiverse           | source, amd64`

but the raspberry pi is *armhf* or *arm64* which is the wrong architecture; thus cannot install/run `virtualbox`

You're missing the importance of *architecture*, ie. what the CPU understands & can run  (ie. it won't run if using *s390x*, *ppc64el* or other architecture either... it's requires *amd64*)

Answer (score 5):

VirtualBox does not run on ARM CPUs like the Raspberry Pi's CPU. However, if what I've read in the past is not misleading me, the Raspberry Pi's CPU does support virtualization, and you should be able to use QEMU to run virtual machines on it. This documentation might help you: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM

Comment: VMware ESXi runs on RPi too